# Getting RDF/XML web page using GET request with Accept header in Java

Tags: java, get, rdf

I want to send a GET requests that accept only results of type `application/rdf+xml` using the `Accept:` header. Is the following code right?

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/rdf+xml");
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: i can't see anything wrong . is there any problem using this code?

Comment: That's because Accept header is using as a suggestion for the server, not an enforcement, and there is no way you can enforce it.

Comment: @gigadot would you like to make an answer of your comment?

Answer (score 0):

@gigadot nailed it, the `Accept` header is a suggestion to the server which the server is free to ignore.

If your application can only accept RDF/XML then you need to add logic to the receipt of the request to enforce this.

You can use the `getContentType()` method of a `URLConnection` to see what content type the server returned you and take an appropriate action (e.g. report an error) if it does not match your requirements.